# Calling a method concurrently in a singleton class

Tags: java, concurrency, singleton

Let's say I have created a singleton class called Calculator with a method add that takes 2 parameters.

```
public class Calculator {
    private static Calculator instance = new Calculator();

    public static Calculator getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public int add(int num1, int num2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

**Case 1:**
Now since it is singleton, will there be any issues if we call the method `add` concurrently say 10,000's of times?

**Case 2:** 
If this class is not singleton, and a normal class then what will happen if I do the same thing, calling it concurrently.

**Case 3:**
Now if my class is not singleton and if my add method is a static method then how the memory will be used?

So my doubt is how it behaves, what is the Java memory model in the given scenarios. Which is efficient or recommended one? Can you please help me in understanding this?

Comment: You're supplying `add` with two primitive variables and your method only handles them, no field or anything else that is shared among many instances. Unless there's some elaborate use of these primitives, singleton nor concurrency matters here.

Comment: 1) no issues, 2) no difference, 3) still no issues. There are no concurrency or performance issues to worry about. You do have to wonder if this is the simplest code you could have and whether there is a maintainability overhead in actually doing this, or whether using such a method is needlessly confusing for a human to deal with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Case 1: Now since it is singleton, will there be any issues if we call
>   the method add concurrently say 10,000's of times?

There is no concurrency issue here: the method `add` doesn't have any side-effects (it doesn't change the state of the object).

> Case 2: If this class is not singleton, and a normal class then what
>   will happen if I do the same thing, calling it concurrently.

Same answer as the previous one.

> Case 3: Now if my class is not singleton and if my add method is a
>   static method then how the memory will be used?

Same answer as the previous two: it doesn't matter if the method is static or not, every time it's called with the two parameters it will perform the calculation on these parameters without changing the state of the instance/class.

> So my doubt is how it behaves, what is the Java memory model in the
>   given scenarios. Which is efficient or recommended one? Can you please
>   help me in understanding this?

Again, it doesn't matter. There will be no concurrency issues because no state is being modified. This has nothing to do with concurrency or with JMM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alfasin. I don't know much on Java memory model, but as per my knowledge there is something called method stack in memory, during singleton this method stack can create issues. And some people say static methods are an overhead. Can you please explain in that perspective.

Comment: When a method is ran, regardless if it's static or not, it is loaded into the stack (vs. heap - where the objects are created). This has nothing to do with being a singleton or with thread-safety. As for static methods as an overhead - I never heard of it.

Answer (score -1):

There is no issue if the method called concurrently. for all your case there is no issue. **There will be no concurrency issues because no state is being modified**. So nothing will impact.

If want to access it in multi-threaded environment then you need to make it as `synchronised` to thread safe.

Comment: Can you please explain why I need to synchronise this method with clear explanation?

Comment: you need not required to synchronise I put it because  If you are calling it in multi threaded environment for thread safe purpose

Comment: Can you please explain the same? How does it affect in multi-threaded environment, I do not have instance variables here right.

Comment: If two or more thread access the same object same time it may impact on the object state. A piece of code is thread-safe if it only manipulates shared data structures in a manner that guarantees safe execution by multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: Thread safety doesn't necessarily mean that you have to use the `synchronised` keyword.

Comment: its not a recommendation I just know one of the way.